# Is it possible to create an abstract method with a dynamic signature?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I have a .Net 5 Web Api project with multiple controllers acting like actions that should always return a statuscode of 200 with a `Guid` representing the causation id.

I created a base class for these command handlers

```
[ApiController]
public abstract class CommandController : ControllerBase
{
    [NonAction]
    protected CausationIdResult CausationId(Guid causationId) => new(causationId);
    
    public abstract Task<CausationIdResult> Handle(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public sealed class CausationIdResult : OkObjectResult
{
    public CausationIdResult(Guid causationId) : base(causationId) { }
}
```

A sample implementation could be

```
public sealed class DoSomethingController : CommandController
{
    [HttpPost("do-something")]
    public override Task<CausationIdResult> Handle(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // run logic here

        // generate a unique queue id

        // pass the queue id back to the client
        return Task.FromResult(CausationId(Guid.NewGuid()));
    }
}
```

but what if I want to expect additional parameters from that controller action? E.g. reading the parameters, queries or the body?

This is another example showing what might get implemented

```
[HttpPost("do-something/{id}")]
public override Task<CausationIdResult> Handle(CancellationToken cancellationToken, [FromRoute] string id)
{
    return Task.FromResult(CausationId(Guid.NewGuid()));
}
```

but obviously this causes compile errors because

> There is no suitable method for override

Is it possible to create an abstract method with dynamic parameters like so?

```
public abstract Task<CausationIdResult> Handle(CancellationToken cancellationToken /* , a type that makes it possible to add all the additional parameters here */);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to interpret your question and slightly pivot the solution.
The original problems is:

> actions that should always return a status code of 200 with a Guid

You are trying to solve this problem using inheritance and that is where you hit another problem:

> Is it possible to create an abstract method with dynamic parameters like so?

Because the code runs within ASP.NET core stack, we now have more tools at our disposal that could help us addressing the original problem. If you are not hard-constrained to use inheritance, you could use either [ASP.NET middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-5.0) or [ASP.NET MVC filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0).
As noted in one of the [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-exceptions-to-modify-the-response):

> The contents of the response can be modified from outside of the controller.

Your filter would look something like that:

```cs
public class HttpResponseCausationFilter : IActionFilter, IOrderedFilter
{
    protected CausationIdResult CausationId(Guid causationId) => new(causationId);    

    public int Order { get; } = int.MaxValue - 10;

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) { }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {        
         context.Result = new ObjectResult(CausationId(Guid.NewGuid()))
         {
            StatusCode = 200,
         };  
    }
}
```

and don't forget to register the filter

```cs
services.AddControllers(options =>
    options.Filters.Add(new HttpResponseCausationFilter()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The best fit could be [`params`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) syntax, but in the end you wouldn't figure out the meaning of subsequent parameters.

Why not taking an entirely different approach? Like using an `IDictionary` to store *dynamic* arguments. By *dynamic*, I mean that the `CausationIdResult`, which is *isolated*, is unaware of possible values injected into it.

In order to make it work, you would expose the possibility to create an instance of `CausationResult` with a dynamic (hence key-value-pair) data type.

Oh, C# supports [dynamic types](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) as well.

In the end I believe you have a X->Y problem. You are trying to solve a compilation problem when your problem is tracking input into your result class.